# is it possible to create a condition with element background color?

Tags: if-statement, background-color

for example, I wanna finish a task when all my elements of a div have the same color, how can I do that?

```
if (a.style.backgroundColor == "red) { 
    (block of command)
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but potentially complex (since most browsers return the the `color` and `background-color` in `rgb()` (or `rgba()`) format, rather than simply `red`), you may require some means to convert between the various other, different, color-formats (`hsl()`, `rgb()`, `hwb()`, `lab()`, `lch()`...). What have you tried, though, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please edit that code into your question; users shouldn't have to read the comments to find relevant information (and it's horribly difficult to read in comments anyway). It's also worth remembering that comments are prone to deletion. You should, also, take the time to read both the "[ask]," and "[mcve]," guidance.